# Report showing as Pass though i intenationally failed it in beforemethod

Tags: selenium, testng

In my below code - Report always show testcase as Pass though i failed the testcase at BeforeMethod. Please help me to fix this problem

```
public class practice extends Test_CommonLib {
    WebDriver driver;
    ExtentReports logger;
    String Browser="FireFox";

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
            logger=eno_TestResport(this.getClass().getName(),Browser);
            logger.startTest(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
            Assert.assertTrue(false); //intentionally failing my BeforeMethod

    }

    @Test
    public void CreateObject() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
    public void tearDown(ITestResult result) throws Exception{
        if (ITestResult.FAILURE==result.getStatus()) {
            logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test case failed");
        }else if(ITestResult.SKIP==result.getStatus()){
            logger.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Test case skipped");
        }else {
            logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Aweosme Job");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: in simple english `@BeforeMethod` & `@AfterMethod` are not your actual tests; only `@Test` are you tests

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you are observing is correct. When an Assertion fails the rest of the code is not executed. The same is happening in your case as well. Irrespective of your Assertion whether it passes/fails driver is no more executing any code within that method & straightly comes out of @BeforeMethod Annotation and moves to the methods under @Test Annotation.

Further, your report will always show Testcase as "Pass" as your Testcase within @Test Annotation will successfully execute.

@AnandKakhandaki Here you need to follow certain guidelines of TestNG following this page - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_basic_annotations.htm
It is worth mentioning that, the piece of code within `BeforeMethod` Annotation will be executed everytime before executing any method. Likewise for `BeforeSuite`, `BeforeClass`, `BeforeTest` & `BeforeGroups`. Similarly, the piece of code within `AfterMethod` Annotation will be executed everytime after executing any method. Likewise for `AfterSuite`, `AfterClass`, `AfterTest` & `AfterGroups`. The code within these mentioned Annotation should be used to configure the Application aka System under test before and after the actual test execution begins/ends. These Annotation may include code for choosing the browser for test execution, opening/closing the browser with certain attributes, opening a url, switch to other url, closing the url, etc which are mandatory configurations to run the test execution.

Validation/Verification or Assertion should never be part of these Annotations. Rather, Assertions should be within `Test` Annotation. To be precise, Assertions should be kept out of `Test` Annotation as well, in a separate library. So your code with in `Test` Annotation contains only Testing Steps.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Well i have some specific code in the beforemethod, so I wish, if BeforeMethod fails then it should skip Testmethod and should go directly to AfterMethod where i have reporting code. - Currently this is working as expected. But Why my Report showing result as Pass as Testcase is failed due to assertion failed at @ BeforeMethod???

Comment: @AnandKakhandaki Check my updated Answer & let me if any queries.

Answer (score 0):

with the same code i got result as given below:-

[image]

Comment: Well i have some specific code in the beforemethod, so I wish, if BeforeMethod fails then it should skip Testmethod and should go directly to AfterMethod where i have reporting code. - Currently this is working as expected.

But Why my Report showing result as Pass as Testcase is failed due to assertion failed at @ BeforeMethod???